# HeatMap on pandas python 3.7

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a beautiful heatMap using pandas. The data is a csv file, is in the same folder of the script python.

I got an error in my code, is easy:

```
File "<ipython-input-6-1b7ca215e6d0>", line 4
    fid = datadf u'/my_Path/File.csv'
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I think the important reason is not the syntax.
So I need to your help ?

My code is:

```
datadf = pd.read_csv("D:\my_Path\File.csv")
## Loading the data
fid = datadf u'/my_Path/File.csv'
key = u'dataset_key'

## Load the dataframe
df = pd.read_hdf(fid,key)

## Default plot ranges:
long_range = (datadf['long'].min(), datadf['long'].max())
lat_range = (datadf['lat'].min(), datadf['lat'].max())

## France plot ranges
long_range_fr = (-5,10)
lat_range_fr = (40,52)

## Visualization
### Custom functions
def bg(img):
    return tf.set_background(img,"black")

def create_image(long_range=long_range, lat_range=lat_range, w=800, h=800):
    cvs = ds.Canvas(x_range=long_range, y_range=lat_range, plot_height=h, plot_width=w)
    agg = cvs.points(df, 'lon', 'lat')
    return bg(tf.shade(agg, cmap = cm(Hot,0.2), how='eq_hist'))


### Statit plot
create_image(long_range=long_range_fr, lat_range=lat_range_fr)
```

A sample of my data:

```
long        lat
-0.91655    43.456863
-0.495795   43.162117
-0.029272   43.097401
-0.108955   43.233845
-0.10237    43.207676
-0.096726   43.19257
-0.102862   43.216438
-0.1091     43.234241
-0.105826   43.225636
-0.096518   43.190247
-0.098496   43.19902
-0.079585   43.229698
-0.081321   43.232929
-0.079448   43.232937
-0.624699   43.364143
-0.429526   43.328094
```

Comment: Try using seaborn heatmap, it is mutch easier than your solution i guess. 
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Comment: @KristófVarga Ok but How can I import my data ? because my file contain 2 columns: longitude and latitude.

Comment: @KristófVarga I gived you sample of my data. Can you help me please to plot a heatmap ? Thank you

Comment: The data sample you say you have provided is not in the question. Would you try again?

Comment: While this question is not being repaired, I have rolled it back to its last readable state. More edits are welcome, but **only if they do not make it unanswerable again**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rightly mentioned by @Kristóf Varga seaborn heatmap can be used to find the appropriate solution.

A solution can be found over here: [Using seaborn heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025097/using-seaborn-heatmap)

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I can't find the best solution for the case of the type of my data. Can you help me please ?  Thank you

Comment: @Dervarshi Mandal I want do a heatMap of a geolocalisation.